# Parsing a vector in R

Tags: r

I have some problem in R that I couldn't figure out what went wrong.

I have a vector containing names of a dataframe:

```
variable_name <- c("radius_mean","texture_mean","perimeter_mean","area_mean","smoothness_mean","compactness_mean","concavity_mean","concave points_mean","symmetry_mean")
```

I tried to use the variable_name as an argument to the function: as.formula

```
as.formula(paste("diagnosis ~", paste(v_name, collapse = " + ")))
```

basically I tried to generate a formula in R symbolically to get something like this:

```
diagnosis ~ radiums_mean + texture_mean + ... + concave points_mean
```

But I keep getting this error message:

Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) : 
  :1:133: unexpected symbol
1: diagnosis ~ radius_mean + texture_mean + perimeter_mean + area_mean + smoothness_mean + compactness_mean + concavity_mean + concave points_mean

```
                                               ^
```

However when I removed the character "concave points_mean" from my variable_name vector: say

```
variable_name_new <- c("radius_mean","texture_mean","perimeter_mean","area_mean","smoothness_mean","compactness_mean","concavity_mean")

as.formula(paste("diagnosis ~", paste(variable_name_new, collapse = " + ")))
diagnosis ~ radius_mean + texture_mean + perimeter_mean + area_mean + 
smoothness_mean + compactness_mean + concavity_mean
```

I was able to get what I want. So my question is what is wrong with the first vector when I have the character "concave points_mean" in the variable_name vector?
I really don't know what is causing the problem.

Comment: The problem is that “concave points_mean” has a space in it, and spaces are not allowed in names. Simplest fix is to remove the space.

Answer (score 2):

Surround each variable name with backticks:

```
paste("diagnosis ~", paste(sprintf("`%s`", variable_name), collapse = "+"))
```

Another possibility is this where `DF` is the data frame holding the data.  It avoids having to name the variables so non-syntactic names won't interfere.

```
lm(diagnosis ~., DF[c("diagnosis", variable_name)])
```

If there are no other variable names other than `diagnosis` and the names in `variable_name` then it could be shortened to:

```
lm(diagnosis ~., DF)
```

This would work too:

```
lm(DF[c("diagnosis", variable_name)])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. But may I know what the backticks do? because I see that my vector of variable_name now has this: "`radius_mean`"             "`texture_mean`"

Comment: there is a little ` in the front and at the back of the variable name

Comment: also what is the percentage sign with s? %s?

Comment: If variable names are within backticks the name will be regarded as a valid name even if it would not have been otherwise.  Read `?sprintf` for information on its arguments.